# It's possible to start a binding.pry session passing a command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

I have added an alias on RSpec using `pry-byebug`, just like this:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

RSpec.configure do |rspec|
  rspec.alias_example_group_to :pcontext, pry: true
  rspec.alias_example_group_to :pdescribe, pry: true
  rspec.alias_example_to :pit, pry: true

  rspec.before(:example, pry: true) do |_|
    # rubocop:disable Lint/Debugger
    binding.pry
    # rubocop:enable Lint/Debugger
  end
end
```

I would like that when using this alias, for example in this line of code:

```rb
pit { expect(published_post.published?).to be_truthy }
```

For the session to start on the test line like this:

```rb
...
=> 16:     pit { expect(published_post.published?).to be_truthy }
```

But at moment it start inside the alias:

```rb
From: /opt/hobbyonrails/spec/support/alias.rb:12 :

       7: 
       8:   rspec.before(:example, pry: true) do |_|
       9:     # rubocop:disable Lint/Debugger
      10:     binding.pry
      11:     # rubocop:enable Lint/Debugger
 => 12:   end
    13: end
```

To go to where I want I need to run this command: `step 25`. So, I was wondering if there is a way to have this command run automatically right after the session starts, but I can't find the answer.

Can you give me some tips to achieve this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Pry `before_session` hook as described in [the Pry wiki article on hooks](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Hooks#Hooks_before_session_event).

A `before_session` hook is executed before dropping you into the REPL when `binding.pry` is called. Pry uses a `before_session` hook every time you invoke `binding.pry` to call [`whereami --quiet`](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/master/lib/pry/hooks.rb#L20), like you have in your post:

```
From: /opt/hobbyonrails/spec/support/alias.rb:12 :

       7: 
       8:   rspec.before(:example, pry: true) do |_|
       9:     # rubocop:disable Lint/Debugger
      10:     binding.pry
      11:     # rubocop:enable Lint/Debugger
 => 12:   end
    13: end
```

The idea of using a `before_session` hook to solve your problem is to tell Pry that when it is invoked it should automatically call `step 25`. (or however many steps you need)

It gets a little bit tricky though because the `step` command from pry-byebug actually invokes a new Pry session. If you add a `before_session` hook that calls `step`, and `step` then invokes a new session, you'll get caught in a loop that steps through until the program finishes executing.

Another issue is that any invocation of `binding.pry` in your code that is executed after the hook is added will invoke `step` again, and you probably don't want it to `step` every time, just in one particular spot.

The fix for this is to add a hook that removes itself when executed:

```
Pry.hooks.add_hook(:before_session, 'step') do |output, binding, pry|
  Pry.hooks.delete_hook(:before_session, 'step')
  pry.run_command('step 1')
end
```

Now the flow should be:

1. The hook above is added
2. `binding.pry` is invoked
3. The hook above is executed, removing the hook and running `step 1`
4. `step` invokes a new Pry session
5. The hook above is no longer present and is not executed
6. The REPL opens
7. Any further `binding.pry` invocations do not execute the hook

Here is an example app to show how this would work:

```
require 'pry'
require 'pry-byebug'

Pry.hooks.add_hook(:before_session, 'step') do |output, binding, pry|
  Pry.hooks.delete_hook(:before_session, 'step')
  pry.run_command('step 1')
end

binding.pry
puts 'Pry will run `whereami` and point at this line with => first'
puts 'But when the hook runs it will step to and point at this line with =>'
puts 'And it will stop before it reaches this line'

binding.pry
puts 'And after this second binding, there will be no hook and thus no step'
puts 'And it will stop before it reaches this line'
```

And here's its output demonstrating that it works as described:

```
$ ruby foo.rb

From: /Users/foo/foo.rb:10 :

     5:   Pry.hooks.delete_hook(:before_session, 'step')
     6:   pry.run_command('step 1')
     7: end
     8:
     9: binding.pry
 => 10: puts 'Pry will run `whereami` and point at this line with => first'
    11: puts 'But when the hook runs it will step to and point at this line with =>'
    12: puts 'And it will stop before it reaches this line'
    13:
    14: binding.pry
    15: puts 'And after this second binding, there will be no hook and thus no step'

Pry will run `whereami` and point at this line with => first

From: /Users/foo/foo.rb:11 :

     6:   pry.run_command('step 1')
     7: end
     8:
     9: binding.pry
    10: puts 'Pry will run `whereami` and point at this line with => first'
 => 11: puts 'But when the hook runs it will step to and point at this line with =>'
    12: puts 'And it will stop before it reaches this line'
    13:
    14: binding.pry
    15: puts 'And after this second binding, there will be no hook and thus no step'
    16: puts 'And it will stop before it reaches this line'

foo|(main):1 ⇒ exit
But when the hook runs it will step to and point at this line with =>
And it will stop before it reaches this line

From: /Users/foo/foo.rb:15 :

    10: puts 'Pry will run `whereami` and point at this line with => first'
    11: puts 'But when the hook runs it will step to and point at this line with =>'
    12: puts 'And it will stop before it reaches this line'
    13:
    14: binding.pry
 => 15: puts 'And after this second binding, there will be no hook and thus no step'
    16: puts 'And it will stop before it reaches this line'

foo|(main):1 ⇒
```

Integrating this into your app should be pretty straightforward:

```
rspec.before(:example, pry: true) do |_|
  # rubocop:disable Lint/Debugger
  # You should find a good way to set this value as it seems likely to change
  steps = 25

  Pry.hooks.add_hook(:before_session, 'step') do |output, binding, pry|
    Pry.hooks.delete_hook(:before_session, 'step')
    pry.run_command("step #{steps}")
  end

  binding.pry
  # rubocop:enable Lint/Debugger
end
```

Comment: Regarding the steps variable, I think the only way to make them more accurate would be to add a command in the pry that jumps only to project files, not to gem files. With that, steps 25 would change to this new command and it would only need one "step". I will try to make this contribution in the near future and with that and your answer, I think this alias will be great. Thank you!